# Horizontally align stacked radio buttons in center of Bootstrap grid

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

```
    <!-- 
    Bootstrap docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs
    -->
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 text-center">
            <input id="show_imagery_buttons" type="checkbox">
            <label for="show_imagery_buttons">
            <span data-toggle="tooltip"
                title="Check to request an additional image type"><b>Additional Imagery</b>
            </span>
            </label>
            <ul id="imagery_buttons">
                <li class="radio">
                    <label><input type="radio" id="addImgPng" name="imagery"
                        value="png">PNG</label>
                </li>
                <li class="radio">
                    <label><input type="radio" id="addImgJpg"
                        name="imagery" value="jpg">JPG</label>
                </li>
                <li class="radio"><label><input type="radio" id="addImgPdf"
                    name="imagery"
                    value="pdf">PDF</label>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 text-center">
            <input id="show_dataset_buttons" type="checkbox">
            <label for="show_dataset_buttons">
            <span data-toggle="tooltip"
                title="Check to request another report format"><b>Additional Report Format</b>
            </span>
            </label>
            <ul id="dataset_buttons">
                <li class="radio"><label><input type="radio" id="addDataPDF"
                    name="report"
                    value="pdf">PDF</label>
                </li>
                <li class="radio"><label><input type="radio" id="addDataNLatex"
                    name="report"
                    value="latex">LaTeX</label></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have two stacks of radio buttons that I want to display next to each other. I want to space them so they are in the middle of the row with equal white space on the outer sides of these radio blocks. I've put them on two bootstrap columns and have managed to keep them in the middle of the column using the text-center class ([see this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/136011/))

While this does keep the buttons in the middle of the bootstrap columns as the window size moves, I'm not able to get the radio buttons to align vertically with each other. I think it's related to using the text-center class, but I'm not sure what to replace it with. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Do you want the radio buttons horizontally or vertically stacked? You have mentioned in your post: "I'm not able to get the radio buttons to align vertically with each other." when it's vertically aligned.

Comment: I want them vertical and "square" with each other. Ideally the radio buttons would line up together vertically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct, your `text-center` class was affecting the alignment of the radio buttons and their labels. You also applied a `hide` class which was making your second set of radio buttons invisible. Removing those will get you two columns of left-aligned radio buttons. Keep in mind that bootstrap columns will adjust as your screen size adjusts, so you may only see them in two columns on larger screens.

```css
#imagery_buttons, #dataset_buttons {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!-- Optional theme -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <input id="show_imagery_buttons" type="checkbox">
      <label for="show_imagery_buttons">
        <span data-toggle="tooltip" title="Check to request an additional image type">
          <b>Additional Imagery</b>
        </span>
      </label>
      <ul id="imagery_buttons">
        <li class="radio">
          <label><input type="radio" id="addImgPng" name="imagery"value="png">PNG</label>
        </li>
        <li class="radio">
          <label><input type="radio" id="addImgJpg" name="imagery" value="jpg">JPG</label>
        </li>
        <li class="radio">
          <label><input type="radio" id="addImgPdf" name="imagery" value="pdf">PDF</label>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <input id="show_dataset_buttons" type="checkbox">
      <label for="show_dataset_buttons">
        <span data-toggle="tooltip" title="Check to request another report format">
          <b>Additional Report Format</b>
        </span>
      </label>
      <ul id="dataset_buttons">
        <li class="radio">
          <label><input type="radio" id="addDataPDF" name="report" value="pdf">PDF</label>
        </li>
        <li class="radio">
          <label><input type="radio" id="addDataNLatex" name="report" value="latex">LaTeX</label>
        </li>        
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This has the radio buttons line up with each other, but now the buttons aren't in the center of the column. Maybe I should have clarified in the original post.Ideally the radio buttons line up with each other, but the "block" of buttons are in the center of the column so I have equal white space on the outsides of the buttons.

Comment: Ahh, for this you can apply a little bit of custom css. You can use `margin-left: auto` and `margin-right: auto` to center, and declare a width that will contain the area that you want to be centered. See the edited answer to see how it is used with your code.

Comment: If you do not have restrictions on browser compatibility, you can also try using flexbox to center: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/